# How to append html content in angular 2 / typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-template

I want to append HTML content into a div('single-pane') using insertAdjacentHTML but nothing happens. Not sure what I am missing here.

Here is my HTML content which I am trying to append--->
***component.html***

```html
  <div #notification class="notification-top-bar" style="display: block;">
  </div>
```

Here is my typescript code where I am appending--->
***component.ts***

```js
export class SiteNotificationComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChildren('notification') private notificationsElements:  QueryList<ElementRef>;
  parentClass: any;

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {} 
 
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.parentClass = document.getElementsByClassName('single-pane')[0];
    this.parentClass.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', 'notificationsElements');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ViewChild instead of ViewChildren if you have only one element of notification type.
And declare it of the type ElementRef.

```
export class SiteNotificationComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('notification') el:ElementRef;
  parentClass: any;

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {} 

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.parentClass = document.getElementsByClassName('single-pane')[0];
    this.parentClass.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', this.notificationsElements.nativeElement.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you have suggested, it appends [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: Try this.notificationsElements.nativeElement.innerHTML. I have updated the answer.